# How to load specific test case from excel using TestCaseSource

Tags: c#, nunit, xunit

In an Excel sheet we have 100 test cases and we would like to load specific test case from the list of test cases using TestCaseSource

I have tried to load test cases like as follow

```
TestCaseSource.LoadTestCases(excelName, sheetName).FirstOrDefault(x => x.TestCaseName == TestCaseName)
```

It is loading only first test case or default. But I wanted to load single test case from any row of the sheet

Comment: Why not using a `Select` statement instead of `FirstOrDefault`?

Answer (score 0):

TestCaseSource should generates 100 test cases based on your parameters.

```
class TestSuite
{

[TestCaseSource("LoadTestCases")]
public void GenerateTestCases(ExcelData data){
//logic
}

private static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> LoadTestCases()
{
  var rows = //logic for mapping excel rows for some model

  foreach(var row in rows)
     yield return new TestCaseData(row).SetTestName(row.Name);
}
```

If you would like to get only single test case from TestCaseSource, you could store parameters like excelName and sheetName in appsettings and from CI you will be able to change your parameters value and during build your single test case will appears. I dont recommend this approach.

Easiest way is...generates 100 or more test cases based on your source "excel" and if you would like to execute only single test just use filter for your test execution like:
dotnet test --filter Name=YourTestCaseNameFromExcel